# elasticsearch kibana regex to find phone number within string field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, sense

I tried using the follow query to search for all those which are like phone number within elastic search.

This was the query I tried. However, it does not give me the right answer.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query": {
            "regexp": {
              "content": "((\\([0-9]{3}\\) ?)|([0-9]-))?[0-9]-[0-9]{4}"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "_id": {
                "query": "1042d6b497124c65b44fdcf86e6986d3.185159"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is to capture numbers in this format within the text (123) 456-7890

I tried this query as well

```
{
 "query": {
   "bool": {
     "must": [
       {
         "query": {
           "regexp": {
             "_all":
             {
               "value" : "content: ((\\([0-9]{3}\\) ?)|([0-9]-))?[0-9]-[0-9]{4}"
             }
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "query": {
           "match": {
             "_id": {
               "query": "1042d6b497124c65b44fdcf86e6986d3.185159"
             }
           }
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

The _id does exist and that is being captured when I write that part of the query separately

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sharath